# Event wrapper is executing twice with my ViewModel

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm using the Event wrapper proposed by [Jose Alcérreca](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) , I'm in Fragment A, it loads the data that it should, when I navigate to Fragment B and come back, the content that has already been handled when I opened Fragment A fires again which it shouldnt since the event has already been executed when the Fragment A started

### Fragment A

```
 private val viewModel by viewModels<LandingViewModel> {
        VMLandingFactory(
            LandingRepoImpl(
                LandingDataSource()
            )
        )
    }

private fun fetchShops() {
        viewModel.fetchShopsList()
            .observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {

                it.getContentIfNotHandled().let { result ->
                    when (result) {

                        is Resource.Loading -> {
                            showProgress()
                        }
                        is Resource.Success -> {
                            hideProgress()
                            landingAdapter.setItems(result.data)
                        }
                        is Resource.Failure -> {
                            hideProgress()
                            showError()
                        }
                    }
                }

            })
    }
```

### ViewModel

```
fun fetchShopList() = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {

            emit(Event(Resource.Loading()))
            try {
                emit(Event(repo.getShopList()))
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                emit(Event(Resource.Failure(e)))
            }
    }
```

Now, when I open this Fragment A at first time, it will load the data as expected, now, if I navigate to Fragment B and come back, it will fire again the fetch when I have already fetched it and stored that in the Event wrapper, in which `it.getContentIfNotHandled()` should return false

Why this happends ?

Comment: SingleLiveEvent is kind of a hack. See discussion here: https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9cc3en/why_use_singleliveevent_livedata_at_all/ LiveData always tries to bring you back to current data *state* when you observe it. If you don't want this behavior, it would be better to use a dedicated event class that only notifies observers that are currently visible and doesn't store a queue.

Comment: where do you call `fetchShops()`?

Comment: in onViewCreated @Blackbelt , but since the event has already been handled, it shouldnt enter inside of it at the second time

Comment: onViewCreated gets called back when the transaction is rolled back, so you call fetchShopList and a new event gets triggered

Comment: but the ViewModel instance should still be alive with the contents of the event that has been already handled